# How can I clear the Cache middleware in go-fiber?

Tags: go, caching, go-fiber

I'm using the fiber framework of golang. I want to Cache some endpoints in my server.
For example:
I have endpoint to get all products like this:**http://127.0.0.1:8080/products**
I'm Caching this endpoint but when products table updated I need to clear Cache of this endpoint. How can I do that ?

Comment: You need to configure that inside `Next` callback so you can skip the cached version. https://docs.gofiber.io/api/middleware/cache

Comment: How can I configure that @JordyBaylac 